# Break image into subimages quickly in Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have loaded a huge image as Numpy array of dimensions `H x W x 3`. I want to split this single image into `15 x 15 grid` and transform it into `225 x H/15 x W/15 x 3` NumPy array where the ordering happens either row-wise or column-wise. Note that `H` and `W` are perfect multiples of 15.

I know that this can be done using two `for` loops as shown below,

```
for row in range(15):
   for col in range(15):
       count+=1
       subimage[count,:,:,:] = img[h1:h2, w1:w2, :]
```

but this takes time (I have to repeat this process for 100,000 images which are very huge).

Is there a faster NumPy code to re-organize a single image into 225 sub-images as illustrated above?

Comment: Does your code the same https://cloudxlab.com/assessment/displayslide/2535/numpy-arrays-example-extracting-a-portion-of-an-image-using-array-slicing ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like most of the time is spent in copying the `hugeimage` array values in the `subimages` array. The only solution I've found to speed up your process is to get the resulted subimages as a list of subarray references instead of a numpy array. This enables to speed up the subimage creation a lot but has 2 drawbacks:

1. You'll need to adapt the following code to the new format.
2. The elements of the list are references to the `hugeimage` so modifying `subimageslist2[i]` array will also alter `hugeimage` array values.

Here is a small script that compares your version and the list version:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Preparation of testdata
R, C    = 15, 15
H, W, D = 400*R, 400*C, 3

hugeimage = np.random.randint(0,255,(H,W,D))

# For loop verion
t_start = time.time()
subimages = np.zeros((R*C,H//R,W//C,D),dtype='int')
count = -1
for row in range(R):
  for col in range(C):
    count+=1
    h1, h2, w1, w2 = row*(H//R), (row+1)*(H//R), col*(W//C), (col+1)*(W//C)
    subimages[count,:,:,:] = hugeimage[h1:h2, w1:w2, :]
print(f'Timer 1: {time.time()-t_start}s')

# For loop list (no copy)
t_start = time.time()
subimageslist2 = []
for row in range(R):
  for col in range(C):
    h1, h2, w1, w2 = row*(H//R), (row+1)*(H//R), col*(W//C), (col+1)*(W//C)
    subimageslist2.append(hugeimage[h1:h2, w1:w2, :])
print(f'Timer 2: {time.time()-t_start}s')
subimages2 = np.array(subimageslist2)
print(f'Timer 2 bis: {time.time()-t_start}s')

print('Results 1&2 are equal' if np.linalg.norm(subimages-subimages2)==0 else 'Results 1&2 differ')
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
Timer 1: 0.38389086723327637s
Timer 2: 0.0003371238708496094s
Timer 2 bis: 0.3779451847076416s
Results 1&2 are equal
```

As you can see, adapting your code to work with the list `subimageslist2` speeds up this portion of code. You can then run `subimages2 = np.array(subimageslist2)` to transform the list of subarray references to a numpy array but this will perform a copy and you'll lose the performance improvement (Timer 2 bis).